# Search query for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in elastic search in the following format

```
{
   "stringindex" : {
   "mappings" : {
  "files" : {
    "properties" : {
      "BaseOfCode" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "BaseOfData" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "Characteristics" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "FileType" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "Id" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "Strings" : {
        "properties" : {
          "FileOffset" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "RO_BaseOfCode" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "SectionName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "SectionOffset" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "String" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "SubSystem" : {
        "type" : "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

My requirement is when I search for a particular string (String.string) i want to get only the FileOffSet (String.FileOffSet) for that string.
How do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you want to perform a nested query and retrieve only one field as the result, but I see problems in your mapping, hence I will split my answer in 3 sections:

1. What is the problem I see:
2. How to query nested fields (this is more ES background):
3. How to find a solution:

**1) What is the problem I see:**

You want to query a nested field, but you don't have a nested field.

**The nested field part:**

The field "Strings" is not nested in the type "files" (nested data without a nested field may bring future problems), otherwise your mapping for the field "Strings" would be something like this:

```
{
  "stringindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "files" : {
        "properties" : {
          "Strings" : {
            "properties" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "String" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: yes, I cut most of the fields, but I did this to easily show that you didn't create a nested field.

With a nested field "in hands", we need a nested query.

**The specific field result part:**

To retrieve only one field as result, you have to include the property "_source" in your query.

**2) How to query nested fields:**

This is more for ES background, if you have never worked with nested fields.

**Small example:**

You define a type with a nested field:

```
{
  "nesttype" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" :     { "type" : "string" },
            "parents" : {
                "type" : "nested" ,
                "properties" : {
                    "sex"       : { "type" : "string" },
                    "name"      : { "type" : "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You create some inputs:

```
{ "name" : "Dan", "parents" : [{ "name" : "John" , "sex" : "m" }, 
                               { "name" : "Anna" , "sex" : "f" }] }

{ "name" : "Lana", "parents" : [{ "name" : "Maria" , "sex" : "f" }] }
```

Then you query, but only fetch the nested field "parents.name":

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "parents",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "sex": "m"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source" : [ "parents.name" ]
}
```

The output of this query is "the name of the parents of all people who have a parent of the sex 'm' ". One entry (Dan) has a father, whereas the other (Lana) doesn't. So it only will retrieve Dan's parents names.

**3) How to find a solution:**

**To fix your mapping:**

You only need to include the type "nested" in the field "Strings":

```
{
  "files" : {
        "properties" : {
            ...
            "Strings" : {
                "type" : "nested" ,
                "properties" : {
                    "FileOffset"    : { "type" : "long" },
                    "RO_BaseOfCode" : { "type" : "long" },
                    ...
                }
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**To query your data:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Strings",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "String": "my string"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source" : [ "Strings.FileOffSet" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by **dan**, but I think he didn't mention it all.

His solution don't work for your question, but I guess you even don't know that.

Consider a scenario where data is like ,

**doc_1**

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Strings": [
    {
      "string": "x",
      "fileoffset": "f1"
    },
    {
      "string": "y",
      "fileoffset": "f2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**doc_2**

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Strings": {
    "string": "z",
    "fileoffset": "f3"
  }
}
```

When you run the like **dan** said, like say let's apply filter with Strings.string=x then response is like,

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "stringindex",
      "_type": "files",
      "_id": "11961",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "Strings": [
          {
            "fileoffset": "f1"
          },
          {
            "fileoffset": "f2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is because, elasticsearch will get hits from documents where any of the object inside nested field (here Strings) pass the filter criteria. (In this case in `doc_1`, `Strings.string=x` passed filter, so `doc_1` is returned. But we don't know which nested object pass the criteria.

So, you have to use [nested_aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html),

Here is a solution for you..

```
POST index/type/_search
{
    "size": 0, 
   "aggs": {
      "StringsNested": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "Strings"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "StringFilter": {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "Strings.string": "x"
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "FileOffsets": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "Strings.fileoffset"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So, response is like,

```
"aggregations": {
      "StringsNested": {
         "doc_count": 2,
         "StringFilter": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "FileOffsets": {
               "buckets": [
                  {
                     "key": "f1",
                     "doc_count": 1
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Remember to have mapping of Strings as nested, as **dan** said.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I am new to elastic search. So this is good learning for me.

Comment: No problem, just making sure you understand elasticsearch. (Because What I've mentioned is important and useful too).