# how to query for values in an object with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

i am trying to figure out how to query on specific fields in an object with elasticsearch.
my indexed document looks like this:

```
{
    name : 'thename'
    meta : {
        title : {value: 'foo is the title'}
        headline: {value : 'bar is the headline'}
    }
}
```

how would i for example create a query against `meta.title.value`?
is this actually supported?
i can can query for those values without specifying a key like:

```
{
    query: 'foo'
}
```

and i get the correct results back but i cant figure out how to do it if i just want to search for that specific key inside the meta object.
more specifically i am using `mongoose` with `mongoosastic` if that makes any difference.

here my document mapping on elasticsearch:

```
"mappings": {
    "asset": {
        "properties": {
            "kind": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "meta": {
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "properties": {
                            "value": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "headline": {
                        "properties": {
                            "value": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "visible": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example of query by a specific field:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "thename"
        }
    }    
}
```

In the example above, "name" is the name of the field you want to query for.

For the case of the nested data (meta.title, for example), you can take a look in the section **"How to query nested fields"** I posted in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203970/3917476 or check the **"nested query"** and **"nested type"** documentation: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#query-dsl-nested-query.

However, I find you should read the ElasticSearch documentation, because querying by a specific field is one of the most basic things (IMHO).
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html

There are many types of queries you can create. Try to go through most of them (for start, I suggest you "match", "term", "bool", "nested", "fuzzy" and "wildcard") creating small examples.

---

**Edit 1**

I have a suggestion for you: do not create fields with the name "value", otherwise we will have to create useless nested queries.

This is a suggestion for your mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "asset": {
        "properties": {
            "kind": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "meta": {
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "headline": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "visible": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this mapping, you use the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "meta",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "description": "foo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you may use this query to your existing mapping:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "meta",
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "description",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "value": "foo"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @dan, i updated my question with the mapping for on elasticsearch. even after reading how to query for nested fields. i would expect to be able to create a query like `meta.title.value:foo` given the index i have. or a mi misunderstanding the last paragraph here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html ?

Comment: the query works now. thank you for pointing me to the right direction

Comment: I have added more information. I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score -1):

with mongodb you will want to do something like this:

query: `{'meta.title.value': 'foo'}`

You obviously have to specify a key. If you want to look among many fields you can use the $or operator

query: `{$or: [{'meta.title.value': 'foo'}, {'meta.headline.value': 'foo'}]}`

This will return each documents which have `foo` as value in `meta.title.value` or in `meta.headline.value`

Comment: guys i don't know whats wrong with you. this is the second answer i get on how to do it with mongo. please read the title and the question. i know how it works in mongo. but that is not what i am asking!

Comment: 'more specifically i am using mongoose with mongoosastic if that makes any difference.' ops it confused me sorry